# Помогите с выборкой записей из другого блога

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу вывести с другого блога все записи по рубрикам и определенные значения произвольных полей и миниатюру записи. Как это делается вообще и можно ли?

Т. е. такого вида

```
[Рубрика]
    [миниатюра записи] [название и линк] [дата записи] [произвольное значение] [произвольное значение]
    ...

[Рубрика]
     ...
```

Понятно, что через wpdb, но как будет выглядеть SELECT запрос? Не хочется городить из нескольких запросов, а одним запросом не понимаю, как сделать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы решить данную задачу с помощью одного `SELECT` запроса достаточно использовать обычный [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.k-press.ru/cs/2009/3/join/join.asp#ID0EHLAC).

Вот пример выборки названия, даты публикации и содержимого записей конкретной рубрики из базы данных WordPress. Сразу оговорюсь, данные этим запросом в своё время выбирались не для использования на сайте под этой CMS. Поэтому `$wpdb` в нём не фигурирует.

```
SELECT `post_title`,`post_date`, `post_content` FROM `wp_terms` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` AS `t2` ON t1.term_id=t2.term_id
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships`AS t3 ON t2.term_taxonomy_id=t3.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS t4 ON t4.ID=t3.object_id
WHERE t2.taxonomy='category' AND t1.term_id=1;
```

В прочем, полагаю, данный пример и так достаточно наглядно пояснят суть решения и Вы сможете доработать его под свои цели.

На всякий случай, [ссылка](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) на описание БД WordPress в официальной документации.

Comment: Спасибо, такой способ как-раз и использовал, но я именно не понимаю, как вывести произвольные значения объединив их в один объект. Если добавить 
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS t5 ON t5.post_id=t3.object_id , то получаю несколько объектов записи, в зависимости от кол-ва произвольных полей.

Comment: Такой результат говорит только о том, что у записи WordPress в этой таблице есть несколько других связанных записей. Попробуйте использовать дополнительный отбор по полям таблицы `wp_postmeta`